# Homestead does not start in windows with wamp

Tags: laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

thanks for reading my question, I installed laravel, virtualbox, and vagrant on my Windows 10 x64 pc, I use wamp to work.

I created my ssh credentials this way

[image: SSH Credentials]

After that I made a homestead make and vagrant up but I always get this error:

[image: Vagrant Error]

The keys are generated and for some reason the vagrant does not detect the private key (I think)

What could be happening and how to make run the homestead without any trouble?

Comment: can you `vagrant ssh` (i.e. connect to the VM) ? try booting with gui mode and see what/if any error message

Comment: @FrédéricHenri yes I can with putty, but when I login, the window keeps blank, booting the gui, same way, it starts, I see the grub, and again blank, with no error message